# ID of a purple fungus in Virginia

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Could someone tell me a bit more about this fungus found growing in a nearly straight line in the lawn in a wooded area of Virginia, USA? It seems rather fragile, maybe a bit "dry"

[image: redish mosstype]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a moss, but a fungus of the family Clavariaceae. Most likely this is [***Clavaria zollingeri***, commonly known as violet coral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clavaria_zollingeri), but there are a few resembling species. Microscopy might be needed to be entirely sure.

The species is saprotrophic, so it grows on the woody debris in your picture.

[image]